# Advise needed on outsourcing the recording of unique views

Tags: php, codeigniter, statistics

I have an online image sharing platform based on PHP5 + CodeIgniter. I would like the application to show to the user the number of unique views per image. Users can access image pages anonymous or signed in.

Although I know how to implement such a thing myself, I prefer to "outsource" the recording of unique pageviews, for reasons of performance and complexity (determining unique pageviews). My requirements for such a service:

- Must record **unique** page views
- Must have an API that allows me to get the #pageviews for one specific page programmatically. This goes beyond just displaying it, I may need to do calculations with this number
- Semi-realtime information is good enough. Reasonable delays are acceptable
- Low cost or free

**My question is:** Do you know of such a service and which one would you recommend or have experience with? In your answer, please assume an "outsourced" scenario, not DIY.

Comment: What is a unique view to you - one view per visitor? Over what time span?

Comment: Yes, one view per visit is what I call unique. It is about how many users have seen the image page. Concerning the timespan, I would say one month.

Comment: Correction, I meant one view per visitor.

Answer (score 0):

[Piwik](http://www.piwik.org) is a self-hosted, Open Source tool that sports an [API](http://dev.piwik.org/trac/wiki/API/CallingTechniques). I have no experience with it yet, but looking at the API docs, it might be able to do what you need (no guarantees though).

Comment: It looks interesting, thank you. Still, I am looking for an outsourced solution. I do not consider self hosting to be outsourcing :)